# Problem with serial port

Tags: 12.04, serial-port

I am unable to access the serial port on my PC with Ubuntu 12.04.

The command:

```
dmesg | grep ttyS
```

Outputs:

```
[    0.590705] 00:08: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
```

I think serial port is not getting detected.

Can anyone please help me in solving the problem?

Comment: Please post the output of `ls /dev/ttyS*`. Did you have any serial device to test the port (i.e. Serial Arduino, printer, serial mouse... etc.)?

Comment: /dev/ttyS0   /dev/ttyS14  /dev/ttyS2   /dev/ttyS25  /dev/ttyS30  /dev/ttyS8
/dev/ttyS1   /dev/ttyS15  /dev/ttyS20  /dev/ttyS26  /dev/ttyS31  /dev/ttyS9
/dev/ttyS10  /dev/ttyS16  /dev/ttyS21  /dev/ttyS27  /dev/ttyS4
/dev/ttyS11  /dev/ttyS17  /dev/ttyS22  /dev/ttyS28  /dev/ttyS5
/dev/ttyS12  /dev/ttyS18  /dev/ttyS23  /dev/ttyS29  /dev/ttyS6
/dev/ttyS13  /dev/ttyS19  /dev/ttyS24  /dev/ttyS3   /dev/ttyS7

Comment: this is the output i got when i tried that command

Comment: Can you check that you have access to read and write in `ttyS01`. In my case `ls -l /dev/ttyS0` returns: `crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 64 May  8 08:20 /dev/ttyS0` and I can use it with no problems.

Answer (score 8):

> ```
> [    0.590705] 00:08: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
> ```

The line above tell us that the kernel detected a [16550 UART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16550_UART) chip in your PC, which provides a serial port (ttyS0), and there's some resources allocated to it ([0x3f8 I/O address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output_base_address#Common_I.2FO_base_address_device_assignments_in_IBM_PC_compatible_computers), [IRQ 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_request_%28PC_architecture%29#Master_PIC)).

The default permissions for serial devices are the following:

```
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout ... /dev/ttyS0
```

So, if you are a member of the `dialout` group, you'll be able to access (read from/write to) the serial port devices. Add yourself to the `dialout` group by running:

```
sudo adduser $USER dialout
```

Or:

```
sudo adduser <username> dialout
```

Then log out and log in again. Now you should have access to the serial port. Of course, you must also input the correct settings (speed, data bits, parity, stop bits, flow control) in the program you're using to access the device.